# Rails nested resources not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I was trying to add Stripe to my Rails application following this tutorial, but couldn't figure out what went wrong:

[Assigning Charges To Resources With Stripe Checkout](https://coderwall.com/p/vm1k7a/assigning-charges-to-resources-with-stripe-checkout)

Below is my code,

routes.rb

```
  resources :people, :path => "" do
    member do
      put :activate
      put :deactivate
    end
    resources :listings do
      member do
        put :close
        put :move_to_top
        put :show_in_updates_email
      end
      resources :charges
    end
```

and in the.haml

```
= form_tag listings_charges_path(@listings) do
```

but there is error like below:

```
undefined method `listings_charges_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f0690ea1788>:0x007f06b1864b88>

      = form_tag listings_charges_path(@listings) do
```

Is it because the charges is nested inside listings resource, and listings is also nested in another one? It's weird cause it's totally working fine if I changed the code back to none nested resources.

```
= form_tag charges_path do
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks!

**This worked, but there is something new:**

```
          = form_tag person_listing_charges_path(@person, @listing, @charges) do
```

**New error:**

```
No route matches missing required keys:{:action=>"index", :controller=>"charges", :id=>"111-abc", :listing_id=>nil, :locale=>nil, :person_id=>#<Listing id: 111, ..........} [:listing_id]
```

Comment: You also need to pass `@charge` object in side that path method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is `people_listing_charge_path(@people, @listing, @charge)` if you want to do this. Or maybe `person_listing_charge_path(@person, @listing, @charge)` depending on how Rails helper works. As you can see, it gets pretty cumbersome to handle.

If you check [Rails guide on nested route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), it suggests some ways to handle the nesting. I highly suggest you follow these suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, @Harfangk!

**This worked, but there is something new:**

              = form_tag person_listing_charges_path(@person, @listing, @charges) do

**New error:**

    No route matches missing required keys:{:action=>"index", :controller=>"charges", :id=>"111-abc", :listing_id=>nil, :locale=>nil, :person_id=>#<Listing id: 111, ..........} [:listing_id]

Answer (score 0):

You probably should do (if your people singular is person)

```
person_listing_charge_path(@person, @listing, @charge)
```

To know your routes, you can do `rake routes`

FYI: According to [ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

> Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.

Comment: Thanks, @XavM!

**This worked, but there is something new:**

              = form_tag person_listing_charges_path(@person, @listing, @charges) do

**New error:**

    No route matches missing required keys:{:action=>"index", :controller=>"charges", :id=>"111-abc", :listing_id=>nil, :locale=>nil, :person_id=>#<Listing id: 111, ..........} [:listing_id]

Comment: It seems there is an error in passing parameters:
listing_id is nil -> are you sure `@listing` is not empty ? person_id is containing a listing object -> are you sure `@person` contain People object ? Could you post your route of person_listing_charge_path (accessible via rake routes).